# How to align the flags (from \worldflag) to the text within a table (and, consequently, remove the resulting whitespace from the table cells)

Tags: tables, white-space

In the following example, it looks like that the [`\worldflag`](https://mirror.init7.net/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/worldflags/doc/worldflags.pdf) command pushes the flags to the top of the table cells, creating some vertical whitespace. How to vertically align the flags to the text within the table, and therefore removing the vertical whitespace inside the table cells?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{worldflags}
\flagsdefault[width=0.5cm]

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|},hlines}
First variable \newline Second variable & \worldflag{FR} \\
First variable & \worldflag{BR} \\
First variable \newline Second variable & \worldflag{CH} \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I make the flags slightly larger, and create `\Worldflag` macro which sets the flag's upper extent to a height of `\ht\strutbox` above the baseline.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{worldflags}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\flagsdefault[width=1.9\baselineskip]
\newcommand\Worldflag[1]{\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\worldflag{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|},hlines}
First variable \newline Second variable & \Worldflag{FR} \\
First variable & \Worldflag{BR} \\
First variable \newline Second variable & \Worldflag{CH} \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

The OP asks how to achieve a similar effect when the flags are made smaller?

Here, I make the flags smaller, add a vertical buffer above and below each flag, via `\addstackgap[.6\ht\strutbox]{...}` and also adjust the vertical shift of the `\belowbaseline`.  While the particular values can be adjusted, I recommend that the stackgap minus the belowbaseline shift add up to `\ht\strutbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{worldflags}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\flagsdefault[width=1\baselineskip]
\newcommand\Worldflag[1]{\addstackgap[.6\ht\strutbox]{%
  \belowbaseline[-0.4\ht\strutbox]{\worldflag{#1}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|},hlines}
First variable \newline Second variable & \Worldflag{FR} \\
First variable & \Worldflag{BR} \\
First variable \newline Second variable & \Worldflag{CH} \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Woww!! Thanks a lot!!! :-) :-)

Comment: Just a small doubt.... In case I make the flags smaller (e.g. \flagsdefault[width=1.2\baselineskip]), how could I vertically center them inside the cells? Indeed, at this moment, the flags are closer to the top lines of the table cells and not vertically centered (you can see it when they are smaller)... :-)

Comment: @Ommo Please see my **ADDENDUM**

Comment: Thanks a lot Steven! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Lower the flag so the height is the same as the height of a strut. Since `longtblr` adds a small padding, flags won't touch the rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{worldflags}

\flagsdefault[width=0.5cm]
\newcommand{\tflag}[1]{%
  \raisebox{\dimeval{\ht\strutbox-\height}}{\worldflag{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{ colspec = {|X|X|},hlines}
First variable \newline Second variable & \tflag{FR} \\
First variable & \tflag{BR} \\
First variable \newline Second variable & \tflag{CH} \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A great answer! Thanks a lot @egreg!!